# how to detect and slice boxes out of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, edge-detection, numpy-slicing

I've got a wide image with 2 images inside it, these 2 images could be seen as 'boxes' in the big image and the numpy array would look like this:

```
[
[200,200,200,157,200,200,200,238,256,167,234,266,154,200,200,200,157,200,200,200,238,256,167,234,266,154,200,200,200,157,200,200,200],
[200,200,200,200,200,200,200,238,256,167,234,266,154,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,238,256,167,234,266,154,200,200,200,200,200,200,200],
[200,144,200,200,132,200,200,238,256,167,234,266,154,200,144,200,200,132,200,200,238,256,167,234,266,154,200,144,200,200,132,200,200],
[200,200,200,200,200,200,200,238,256,167,234,266,154,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,238,256,167,234,266,154,200,200,200,200,200,200,200],
[200,200,166,200,200,200,200,238,256,167,234,266,154,200,200,166,200,200,200,200,238,256,167,234,266,154,200,200,166,200,200,200,200],
[182,200,200,200,200,200,200,238,256,167,234,266,154,182,200,200,200,200,200,200,238,256,167,234,266,154,182,200,200,200,200,200,200]
]
```

[image: These are the boxes]

Because i applied a median filter, the surrounding pixels are all 200 with a little bit of noise here and there. My question is: How can i extract those 2 sub-images from this big image and put them as their own array so i have the pictures seperately. My guess would be to slice them out or maybe use edge detection but i haven't succeeded to do so yet. The array in the question is mockup but represents how it looks like because the real array it too big for the output in visual studio. Underneath is what a picture really looks like, there are different pictures with each different 'white spaces' and amount of sub pictures in it. The size is fixed and always 28 x 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether my assumptions of your image data is correct. The following algorithm only works, if the image itself does not contain
"flat regions" of 200.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = np.array([
[200,200,200,157,200,200,200,238,256,167,234,266,154,200,200,200,157,200,200,200,238,256,167,234,266,154,200,200,200,157,200,200,200],
[200,200,200,200,200,200,200,238,256,167,234,266,154,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,238,256,167,234,266,154,200,200,200,200,200,200,200],
[200,144,200,200,132,200,200,238,256,167,234,266,154,200,144,200,200,132,200,200,238,256,167,234,266,154,200,144,200,200,132,200,200],
[200,200,200,200,200,200,200,238,256,167,234,266,154,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,238,256,167,234,266,154,200,200,200,200,200,200,200],
[200,200,166,200,200,200,200,238,256,167,234,266,154,200,200,166,200,200,200,200,238,256,167,234,266,154,200,200,166,200,200,200,200],
[182,200,200,200,200,200,200,238,256,167,234,266,154,182,200,200,200,200,200,200,238,256,167,234,266,154,182,200,200,200,200,200,200]
])


# filter all regions of (more or less) constant 200
median_data = np.median(data, axis=0)
diff_data = np.append([0], np.diff(median_data))
img_region = (diff_data != 0) & (median_data != 200)

# get image regions, identify longest image as "true" image length
idx_pairs = np.where(np.diff(np.hstack(([False],img_region,[False]))))[0]
region_lengths = np.diff(idx_pairs)[::2]
longest_region = np.max(np.diff(idx_pairs)[::2])

# fix broken images
for i_region, region_length in enumerate(region_lengths):
    if region_length != longest_region:
        try:
            img_region[slice(idx_pairs[i_region*2], idx_pairs[i_region*2]+longest_region)] = True
        except IndexError:
            pass  # removed mini-regions
    idx_pairs = np.where(np.diff(np.hstack(([False], img_region, [False]))))[0]

# get number of images
n_img = np.sum(np.diff(img_region.astype(int)) == 1)
image_data = data[:, img_region]

# slice images
images = np.split(image_data, n_img, axis=1)
for img in images:
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(img)

plt.show()
```

Comment: It looks like it would work! however, with the split (images = np.split(image_data, n_img, axis=1)) it throws this error: array split does not result in an equal division. I looked into the images and they are always 28 x 200 but i don't see why this would be a problem. The split says the number of images should be 8 but in the image there are only 5 images, I edited the question with a picture of the image.

Comment: Unfortunatly, the provided images are riddled with jpeg artifacts, so I cannot easily use them as example data. But I guess that the issues is that other "slices of 200" are detected in the images. I have updated my algorithm assuming that all images are the same size, which should prevent "false" image splits

Comment: It almost works! it outputs 4 of the sub-images and I think the only thing left is that when there are 5 images in the big image it only retrieves 4 but with 4 images it works fine. Unfortunately i can't find a way to paste the real image array in the code since it is in .npy format

Comment: I assume the reason for it "almost" working is that I did not take into account that images with any median column value of 200 will get filtered out by that... I will have to think about that one a little bit longer

Comment: I now try to "fix" the broken images. It's hard to tell whether this approach works without demo data :) - give it a try. I probably will not react to any further comment until tuesday, so... fingers crossed!